# Engine warning light P2191 / Hyundai Veloster problem starting when cold

Tags: engine, starting, fuel-system, obd-ii, hyundai

on monday I had some issues starting the car and then an engine warning light with the code P2191. I clear the error but it appeared again. This is the starting sequence values of o2 and other:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95xgM2H5-5o

It would be so nice if someone with expertise could give me a hint.

I am sorry if this is too specific but I am guessing this might happen to any Kia or Hyundai from 2010 to 2017

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The more specific you are, the better. The code refers to a "System too lean at higher load bank 1" ... now, what exactly that means is another story. I'd check to see if your intake tract is having an issue between the MAF sensor and anywhere through to the intake port on the head. Something where a large amount of air could get into the system on the back side of the MAF.

Comment: Hi Paulster, I checked around that area, the filter seems super clean and I am not sure if I have a MAF (it does not look like the photos of that) seems to be more like a MAP

Comment: If you clear the code, does it just come back?

Comment: Yes, and lately there is a lot of new codes :( I am thinking is something related with the o2 sensors. I have an appointment with hyundai workshop in a week but I just wanted to have a general idea of the issue, or solutions